# Script for Online Tasks

Tags: bots

I was wondering if there is a way to write a script that could perform online tasks . There are actions a user does that is so repetitive/planed, that make me wonder if there is a way i could write a script that could do that for me. What i mean is, for example, a script that could go online, lets say facebook, write/read a post. It seems such a straight forward action that it has to be possible to be done by a scrip.
The thing is I have no idea how to do, my question here is some guidance, if possible, all i need to know is a good language for this and a good aproach. I can't seem to find anything for this, probably not searching the right terms.

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to mock user behavior in the browser (such as filling out a form), you could use Python, a web driver, and the module [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Selenium will open the web driver, then allow you to mock user actions, such as selecting a text box, typing data, and then clicking submit. This allows you automate actions such as a search on a website, verifying a website works the way you expect it to when a user takes certain actions, and filling out input elements on a page and submitting a form.

Comment: Its correct especially for machine learning n automation python is needed but as an easy to begin with approach I will prefer advance java

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand concepts like javascript, ajax, servlets plus advance level concepts like in advance java as these all are event associated for bringing dynamisation to your web page and other than this session level concepts to deal if session is active or expired this all adds to automating based on session attribute.
Finally, at database level you can use triggers to event fire changes when needed.